# Using Ruby Selenium WebDriver how to check URL or Navigation which return 404?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, ruby

What is the most convenient way of using Ruby script for  Selenium WebDriver to check all url's (from navigation menu)of any web page.Actually want to run them to see where they go.

**For example:**

Take - www.google.com and see if it goes to www.google.com (no error/redircts) or if i click to contact from the navigation menu then is it  redirecting to the write page(google.com/contact) or throws a error such as 404, & 500.

Comment: Are you wanting to check response codes? If so, then with webdriver you cant - does this page answer your question? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141

Comment: No i do not want to check response of code.I just want to check the url's.

Comment: what do you mean 'check the urls'? If you want to check 'www.checkthis.com' and it does not exist what are you expecting? what exactly are you trying to test/check?

Comment: For example-I want to browse this site http://www.w3schools.com and want to check all the links in the left side bar. If I click to “Learn HTML5”link and if it returns me  404 or 500 error message then a report will generate as –page not found and result will be marked as fail.
Point is i want to do this ruby script which will support selenium web driver.

Answer (score 3):

You could use next algorithm

1. Get all links from page.
2. Implement ruby script to check all links

**First steps** are implemented in two ways

- Open page by webdriver, and get all links by tag , for example
- Get page by http request and parse html code by regex

**Second step:**

Implement script for request sending

Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby) for implemention script.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks alex thanks for your answer.Can you give me an example of steps 1 and steps 2.

Comment: Get all links from page  base_url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/'
  url = URI.parse(base_url)
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
    http.request(req)
  }
  answer = res.body

 links = answer.scan(/<a.+?href="(.+?)"/)